# Sort table by combined rows

Tags: mysql

I have a database table with over 500 million rows in it, structured as the following:

```
|username  |date      |      units|
|user1     |2015-03-20|          5|
|user2     |2015-03-20|          7|
|user3     |2015-03-20|          3|
|user1     |2015-03-21|          9|
|user2     |2015-03-21|          4|
|user3     |2015-03-21|         11|
```

This is simplified of course, and there are about 2 million unique usernames in the table, each having a new row added every day.

What is the best way to sort by the highest combined total `units` from the past 7 days (or past 7 entries in the database for that user)? I need to see the top 25 or so users, returning their username and their combined `units`.

Answer (score 0):

Filter, group, sort and limit:

```
SELECT   username, SUM(units)
FROM     myTable
WHERE    date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY  -- filter
GROUP BY username                               -- group
ORDER BY SUM(units) DESC                        -- sort
LIMIT    25                                     -- limit
```

This query would be most optimal with a composite index defined over `(username, date, units)`.